# Average of consecutive days in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df` as:

```
Date         Val    WD
1/3/2019     2.65   Thursday
1/4/2019     2.51   Friday
1/5/2019     2.95   Saturday
1/6/2019     3.39   Sunday
1/7/2019     3.39   Monday
1/12/2019    2.23   Saturday
1/13/2019    2.50   Sunday
1/14/2019    3.62   Monday
1/15/2019    3.81   Tuesday
1/16/2019    3.75   Wednesday
1/17/2019    3.69   Thursday
1/18/2019    3.47   Friday
```

I need to get the following `df2` from above:

```
Date         Val    WD
1/3/2019     2.65   Thursday
1/4/2019     2.51   Friday
1/5/2019     3.24   Saturday
1/6/2019     3.24   Sunday
1/7/2019     3.24   Monday
1/12/2019    2.78   Saturday
1/13/2019    2.78   Sunday
1/14/2019    2.78   Monday
1/15/2019    3.81   Tuesday
1/16/2019    3.75   Wednesday
1/17/2019    3.69   Thursday
1/18/2019    3.47   Friday
```

Where the df2 values are updated to have average of consecutive Sat, Sun and Mon values.

i.e. average of  `2.95, 3.39, 3.39` for dates `1/5/2019, 1/6/2019, 1/7/2019` in df is 3.24 and hence in df2 I have replaced the `1/5/2019, 1/6/2019, 1/7/2019` values with 3.24.

The trick has been finding the consecutive Saturday, Sunday and Monday. Not sure how to approach this.

Comment: What happens if you only have a consecutive Saturday and Sunday (no Monday) or even just Saturday Monday? Do you still want to take the average in those cases, or leave the data unchanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CustomBusinessDay` with `pd.grouper` to create a group col:

```
# if you want to only find the mean if all three days are found
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay
days = CustomBusinessDay(weekmask='Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat')

df['group_col'] = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq=days)).ngroup()
df.update(df[df.groupby('group_col')['Val'].transform('size').eq(3)].groupby('group_col').transform('mean'))

    Date          Val          WD     group_col
0   2019-01-03  2.650000    Thursday    0
1   2019-01-04  2.510000    Friday      1
2   2019-01-05  3.243333    Saturday    2
3   2019-01-06  3.243333    Sunday      2
4   2019-01-07  3.243333    Monday      2
5   2019-01-12  2.783333    Saturday    7
6   2019-01-13  2.783333    Sunday      7
7   2019-01-14  2.783333    Monday      7
8   2019-01-15  3.810000    Tuesday     8
9   2019-01-16  3.750000    Wednesday   9
10  2019-01-17  3.690000    Thursday    10
11  2019-01-18  3.470000    Friday      11
```

or if you want to find the mean of any combination of sat sun mon in the same week

```
days = CustomBusinessDay(weekmask='Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat')

df['group_col'] = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq=days)).ngroup()
df['Val'] = df.groupby('group_col')['Val'].transform('mean')
```

Comment: This will average together Sunday/Monday even if there is no Saturday Data.

Comment: @ALollz you are absolutely correct, thanks for pointing that out. It has been corrected.

Answer (score 0):

This logic creates a `Series` that assigns a unique ID to groups of consecutive Sat/Sun/Mon rows in your `DataFrame`. Then ensure there are 3 of them (not just Sat/Sun or Sun/Mon), and `transform` those values with the mean:

```
import pandas as pd
#df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

s = (~(df.Date.dt.dayofweek.isin([0,6]) 
       & (df.Date - df.Date.shift(1)).dt.days.eq(1))).cumsum()

to_trans = s[s.groupby(s).transform('size').eq(3)]
df.loc[to_trans.index, 'Val'] = df.loc[to_trans.index].groupby(to_trans).Val.transform('mean')
```

#### Output:

```
         Date       Val         WD
0  2019-01-03  2.650000   Thursday
1  2019-01-04  2.510000     Friday
2  2019-01-05  3.243333   Saturday
3  2019-01-06  3.243333     Sunday
4  2019-01-07  3.243333     Monday
5  2019-01-12  2.783333   Saturday
6  2019-01-13  2.783333     Sunday
7  2019-01-14  2.783333     Monday
8  2019-01-15  3.810000    Tuesday
9  2019-01-16  3.750000  Wednesday
10 2019-01-17  3.690000   Thursday
11 2019-01-18  3.470000     Friday
12 2019-01-19  3.250000   Saturday
13 2019-01-20  3.250000     Sunday
14 2019-01-21  3.250000     Monday
15 2019-01-22  5.000000    Tuesday
16 2019-01-27  2.000000     Sunday
17 2019-01-28  4.000000     Monday
18 2019-01-29  6.000000    Tuesday
19 2019-02-05  7.000000    Tuesday
20 2019-02-07  6.000000   Thursday
21 2019-02-12  9.000000    Tuesday
```

#### Extended Input Data

```
Date         Val    WD
1/3/2019     2.65   Thursday
1/4/2019     2.51   Friday
1/5/2019     2.95   Saturday
1/6/2019     3.39   Sunday
1/7/2019     3.39   Monday
1/12/2019    2.23   Saturday
1/13/2019    2.50   Sunday
1/14/2019    3.62   Monday
1/15/2019    3.81   Tuesday
1/16/2019    3.75   Wednesday
1/17/2019    3.69   Thursday
1/18/2019    3.47   Friday
1/19/2019    3.75   Saturday
1/20/2019    2.00   Sunday
1/21/2019    4.00   Monday
1/22/2019    5.00   Tuesday
1/27/2019    2.00   Sunday
1/28/2019    4.00   Monday
1/29/2019    6.00   Tuesday
2/5/2019     7.00   Tuesday
2/7/2019     6.00   Thursday
2/12/2019    9.00   Tuesday
```

Comment: Note the `'WD'` column is totally unnecessary since one you convert to `datetime` you can access that information with `Series.dt.dayofweek`

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to calculate a week number, then use `groupby` to calculate means across specific days and map this back to your original dataframe.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# consider Monday to belong to previous week
week, weekday = df['Date'].dt.week, df['Date'].dt.weekday
df['Week'] = np.where(weekday.eq(0), week - 1, week)

# take means of Fri, Sat, Sun, then map back
mask = weekday.isin([5, 6, 0])
week_val_map = df[mask].groupby('Week')['Val'].mean()
df.loc[mask, 'Val'] = df['Week'].map(week_val_map)

print(df)

         Date       Val         WD  Week
0  2019-01-03  2.650000   Thursday     1
1  2019-01-04  2.510000     Friday     1
2  2019-01-05  3.243333   Saturday     1
3  2019-01-06  3.243333     Sunday     1
4  2019-01-07  3.243333     Monday     1
5  2019-01-12  2.783333   Saturday     2
6  2019-01-13  2.783333     Sunday     2
7  2019-01-14  2.783333     Monday     2
8  2019-01-15  3.810000    Tuesday     3
9  2019-01-16  3.750000  Wednesday     3
10 2019-01-17  3.690000   Thursday     3
11 2019-01-18  3.470000     Friday     3
```